# PyTesseract Not Accepting numpy array or PIL Image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, tesseract, python-tesseract

When using pytesseract on numpy and PIL objects, it yields no result. When loading an image directly onto the pytesseract.image_to_string() function, it produces output.

That is, the first 4 test print functions print nothing, the 5th works and the 6th nothing again. The commented out cv2.imshow and img2.show() correctly displays the image (when uncommented of course).

Code below:

```
img = cv2.imread(os.path.join('Images', 'Number Plate Examples', 'B&W Perfect.jpg'))
img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # Convert from BGR (Blue Green Red) format to RGB
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # Convert image to grayscale

img2 = Image.open(os.path.join('Images', 'Number Plate Examples', 'B&W Perfect.jpg'))

#cv2.imshow('image', img_rgb)
#cv2.waitKey(0) 
#img2.show()

print("Test 1: " + pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
print("Test 2: " + pytesseract.image_to_string(img_rgb))
print("Test 3: " + pytesseract.image_to_string(img_hsv))
print("Test 4: " + pytesseract.image_to_string(img_gray))
print("Test 5: " + pytesseract.image_to_string(os.path.join('Images', 'Number Plate Examples', 'B&W Perfect.jpg')))
print("Test 6: " + pytesseract.image_to_string(img2))
```

pytesseract version 0.3.10

Tesseract version 5.2.0.20220712

Image used for Tests:

[image: Sample Image]

**Test Output**

Test 1:

Test 2:

Test 3:

Test 4:

Test 5: 1720 BOM

Test 6:

**Edit** Updated intro and code block to clarify I've tried passing PIL objects too.

Comment: that's a numpy array, not an "opencv object". python-tesseract wants file paths, not arrays in memory.

Comment: Thanks Christoph, though the pytesseract exmaples pass images in memory in. In the example, we see a PIL object (whatever underlying format it uses) being passed. Several other online examples use PIL and even Opencv numpy arrays.
https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/

Is it not possible to pass images in memory to Tesseract?

Comment: This article passes OpenCV numpys to pyteseract too.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/license-plate-recognition-with-opencv-and-tesseract-ocr/
This article:
https://groups.google.com/g/tesseract-ocr/c/Ybvl2OncGHo/m/zSRsvKIsBAAJ
Suggests it can't be done (like you said) and mentions using tesserocr with Pil objects. What would be your suggestion? Saving files to disk seems like wasted time and unnecessary write wear on the storage given I'll be processing short of a million frames per day (will be processing video streams).

Comment: numpy-to-PIL conversion is known stuff. just look it up in the PIL documentation or ask SO. please take the [tour] and review [ask]. you MUST do research. this isn't private tutoring.

Comment: Hi Christopher. I'm not asking how to convert numpy objects to PIL objects. I'm asking why I can't pass a numpy or PIL object to pytesseract when several sources online suggest it can be done and what anyone's suggestion may have been moving forward to achieve this. I've tried researching this but haven't much of a consensus yet. If you aren't interested in answering my question (or private tutoring as you put it), then don't post further on this page. I appreciate any time anyone voluntarily offers in the way of solving this problem. Thanks.

Comment: according to this (they don't have proper docs): https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract#usage passing a PIL Image should have worked. if it didn't, please inspect the Image object you loaded. and perhaps make sure your test code and test output actually go together, i.e. those numbered outputs aren't mistaken.